# Force LibGit2Sharp to interact with files it says are partially locked

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp, filelock

I'm trying to use the C# library LibGit2Sharp to add and commit a binary file while it is open by another program. The `Repository.Index.RetrieveStatus()` call fails with an exception:

> Error reading file for hashing: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.

However the git binary invoked from shell has no problem performing the same action:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   files/foo.bin

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git add files/foo.bin

$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   files/foo.bin
```

Is there a way to convince LibGit2Sharp to behave as [documented](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/Git-status)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a file being held by a another process, if git doesn't cringe when processing it, then libgit2 and LibGit2Sharp shouldn't either.

There's no way to *"Force LibGit2Sharp to interact with files it says are partially locked"*. Because that's a bug and it shouldn't behave this way.

The best course of action for you would now to feed the **[issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/new)** with a new entry so that the team can start and go bug hunting ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was hoping there might have been a `RepositoryOptions` or `StatusOptions` flag I had missed to the effect of "IgnoreLocks" or something.